# Scope data is undefined on hard refresh

Tags: angularjs

Controller code

```
$scope.isActive = $scope.app.user.active;
    $scope.toggleModel = function () {
        $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
          Api.$patch({active: $scope.isActive})
                .then(function(res){
                    $scope.app.user.active = res.active;
                });
    };
```

Template code

```
<button ng-class="isActive?'btn-success':'btn-primary'" ng-click="toggleModel()">{{isActive?'on':'off'}}</button>
```

each time on hard refresh `$scope.app.user.active` is undefined.

Comment: How you are filling `$scope.app.user.active`

Comment: It is the data from storage, got the solution by refreshing storage data.